# Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier line: 13 file: Code.gs

Tags: google-apps-script

```
var sheetId = "1GAioDBvzbvgv_axD2vV2iSnLWP2jGTsztzKdCkWpGNc" //id sheet
var formId = "1xhH_w200uOSui6tYe-vDGWN02lh4r0KVYdgjMOEkQAQ" //id form
  
function myFunction(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId)
var sheet = ss.getSheetId("1GAioDBvzbvgv_axD2vV2iSnLWP2jGTsztzKdCkWpGNc") //sheet name
var form = FormApp.openById(formId)

//Reference Number Short Answer
var data = [...new Set(sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValue().map(row=> row[1]))].join('|')
var item = form.getItems().filter(item=>item.getTitle() == 'Reference Number')[0].asTextItem()
var pattern = '(${data})'
var textval = FormApp.createTextValidation().setHelpText("Already Exists in database").requireTextDoesNotMatchPattern(pattern).build()item.setValidation(textval)}
```

please help i cannot save the formula i keep getting syntax error

Comment: Describe the problem as written in [mcve], specifically stating which line is line 13.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo.  And I didn't find a method of `TextValidationBuilder` `setHelpText()`.

Replace

```
var textval = FormApp.createTextValidation().setHelpText("Already Exists in database").requireTextDoesNotMatchPattern(pattern).build()item.setValidation(textval)}
```

With

```
var textval = FormApp.createTextValidation().setHelpText("Already Exists in database").requireTextDoesNotMatchPattern(pattern).build();
item.setValidation(textval);
}
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getDataRange')
myFunction @ Code.gs:10, can you help me with this?

Comment: var data = [...new Set(sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValue().map(row=> row[1]))].join('|')

Comment: what is wrong in this?

Comment: There is no parameter to [Sheet.getSheetId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetId()).  I think what you want is [Spreadsheet.getSheetByName("SomeName")](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String)).

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getDisplayValue')
myFunction @ Code.gs:10

Comment: I had this another error